# Correct way to use intrinsict IF CloudFormation function

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to use the intrinsic IF CloudFormation function to remove some properties depending of some condition?

Example: Create a provisioned concurrency for a Lambda Function only if the function is running in a production environment.

```
Conditions: 
    ProdCondition:
    Fn::Equals:
    - Ref: Stage
    - prod

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      Fn::If:
      - ProdCondition
      - MemorySize: 1024
        AutoPublishAlias: 'HelloWorldFunctionAlias'
        ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
          ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 10
      - MemorySize: 256
```

I've read the documentation but its quite confusing.

I would like to completly remove some resource properties depending of condition.

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code. Any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWS::NoValue` can be specified as a return value in the `Fn::If` intrinsic function to return a property.

```
HelloWorldFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
  Properties:
    MemorySize:
      Fn::If:
        - ProdCondition
        - 1024
        - 256
    AutoPublishAlias: 
      Fn::If:
        - ProdCondition
        - 'HelloWorldFunctionAlias'
        - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html